# Need to merge 2 rows when 2 variables on 2 columns (total 4 variables) from both rows are the same

Tags: sql-server, case

I need help writing a query that can convert the following table into the second table with SMSS. Basically, in the first table we got a claim processed as primary by Blue Shield Blue Cross for procedure code 99214, and then it was processed by the secondary insurance Medicare. The problem with the report generating the table below is that when we do a sum, it Looks like we got paid 150 out of an allowance of 300 for that claim and procedure code, when in reality we got paid out of the allowance of 150. I will have to merge were Procedure_Code for two rows in a column are the same while the Claim_ID for the same two rows are the same.
I tried pivoting but I don't think I can get the result that way. I am using the case statements

This is the code I wrote:

```
select 

case when [Primary_Insurance] = [Insurance] then [Insurance] end as 'Primary_Insurance',
case when [Primary_Insurance] <> [Insurance] then [Insurance]  end as 'Secondary_Insurance',
        [Claim_ID],
        [Procedure_Code],
        [Allowance],
case when [Primary_Insurance] = [Insurance] then [Insurance_Payment]  end as 'Primary_Payment',
case when [Primary_Insurance] <> [Insurance] then [Insurance_Payment] end as 'Secondary_Payment'


from[dbo].[Sheet1$]
```

I get this:

```
Primary_Insurance,Secondary_Insurance,Claim_ID,Procedure_Code,AllowancePrimary_Payment,Secondary_Payment

BlueShieldBlueCross,NULL,12345,99214,150,100,NULL

NULL,Medicare,12345,99214,150,NULL,50

United Healthcare,NULL,23456,93306,250,200,NULL
```

This approaches to the end result but I still need to combine the first two rows together.

Sample Table

```
Primary_Insurance     Insurance           Claim_ID  Procedure_Code  Allowance   Insurance_Payment   
BlueShieldBlueCross   BlueShieldBlueCross 12345     99214           150         100 
BlueShieldBlueCross   Medicare            12345     99214           150         50  
UnitedHealthcare      UnitedHealthcare    23456     93306           250         200
```

Desired Result:

```
Primary               Secondary  Claim_ID   Procedure_Code  Allowance   Primary_Payment Secondary_Payment
BlueShieldBlueCross   Medicare   12345      99214           150         100             50
UnitedHealthcare      Null       23456      93306           250         200             Null
```

Thank you beforehand for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that there cannot exist a secondary_payment without a corresponding primary_payment. If this assumption is incorrect, we'd have to revisit.

Basically join a copy of the claims table against a subquery of only `null` primary_insurance records from that same table.

```
SELECT
  c1.Primary_Insurance
  ,c2.Secondary_Insurance
  ,c1.Claim_Id
  ,c1.Proc_Code
  ,c1.Allowance
  ,c1.Primary_Payment
  ,c2.Secondary_Payment
FROM claims c1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
    FROM claims WHERE Primary_Insurance IS NULL) c2
ON c1.Claim_Id = c2.Claim_id
  AND c1.proc_code = c2.proc_code
WHERE c1.Primary_Insurance IS NOT NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0705ed/15)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your solution works but only after running the case statements  first and saving the results as a new table. We are always gonna have entries in both the Primary_Insurance and Insurance columns and the case statements get rid of the entries depending on the column if both values match or not, and also add the Secondary Payment column. Do you think there is a better way to approach this?

Comment: @Lumin For clarity, do you have a sample version of the data before you run the case statements? It might be easier to develop if I have some clarity on the original schema and style of data.

Comment: I think this should approximate to the scenarios I find on the report I am working on: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93c36f                                                                                               Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lumin See the query at the link (note, I added an extra row for a claim with only a primary, no secondary). The issue is when there are multiple secondary claims, they each show up. How would you want to handle that? You can sum them up, but then you can't keep detail on the individual line items for each secondary claim. Did you want to create 'tertiary claim' columns? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b2fb5/5

Comment: I was thinking about generating a 'Tertiary Insurance' and 'Tertiary Payment' columns but it might get complicated. The query works, but for multiple secondary payments, it generates duplicate primary payments. I am using case along max and avg to get the data as accurate as possible since payments may vary a lot (we might get negative payments, a lot of denials, and partial payments). Additionally, I tested this on a large report, it reduced unique claims by 20,000. I use distinct CPT and claim ID to determine a unique claim. Do you know why that might happen? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @basodore I replaced the last 'where' clause with 'and' on the query and it seems to return the all the correct values on a smaller sample of the report. I will create an example for my previous comment once I get home. Again thanks for all the help!

Comment: @basodore here is an updated schema. Would it be efficient to insert the results of the previous query into a new table, select distinct, case on payments, and group per primary/secondary insurance, procedure code, and claim id?                                                      http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b31cb/1